# Pagination until the end

Tags: ios, swift, pubnub

I got an app which is using PubNub as a service for the chat. After logging in, I'd like to download all history messages. Unfortunately, PubNub has limited the maximum number of messages to 100, so you have to use pagination to download all of them, until no more messages arrive.
The workflow I'd like to achieve is the following:

1. Load the first 100 messages
2. Handle them (store within the app)
3. Load the next 100 messages
4. And so on..

The Method they provide is the following:

```
client.historyForChannel(channel, start: nil, end: nil, includeTimeToken: false)
{ (result, status) in
      // my code here...
}
```

The thing is, in the "my code here..."-section, I need to call the function again (with a startDate) to load the next 100 messages. But to call the function again, I need to set a completion block which does exactly the same as the completion block which called the function. This is an infinite loop.. How can I solve this differently? Thank you very much!

Comment: "Unfortunately, PubNub has limited the maximum number of messages to 100" - actually, fortunately, or you could end up waiting on millions of messages ;) But agree that PubNub could provide a more developer friend API to retrieve paginated messages via history. The key here is to have a terminating condition that can be checked as it is passed into each recursive call of the function/method. Stay tuned for an answer to this.

Comment: It seems we have a [completed example for JS history pagination](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/storage-and-history#final-paging-history) but not for Swift. This can server as pseudo-code for now but a formal request to our docs team has been submitted to provide for iOS. Please let me know if this serves your purposes for now or if you require further assistance with implementing this code in Swift.

Comment: Here is some sample code from our iOS Engineer for now: 
[history paging backward](https://gist.github.com/parfeon/31d670418c4a28e4ede7) and 
[history paging foreward](https://gist.github.com/parfeon/bc6089abc479201a1c8b)

Comment: See answer below for official docs and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub History Pagination Sample Code

All the SDKs have sample code for implementing history pagination. Please refer to the [PubNub Swift SDK Storage API Reference History Paging section](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/api-reference-storage-and-playback#history_example_4).

Here is the code inlined:

Paging History Responses:
You can call the method by passing 0 or a valid time token as the argument.

```
// Pull out all messages newer then message sent at 14395051270438477.
let date = NSNumber(value: (14395051270438477 as CUnsignedLongLong));
self.historyNewerThen(date, onChannel: "history_channel", withCompletion:  { (messages) in
     
    print("Messages from history: \(messages)")
})
 
 
func historyNewerThen(_ date: NSNumber, onChannel channel: String, 
                      withCompletion closure: @escaping (Array<Any>) -> Void) {
         
    var msgs: Array<Any> = []
    self.historyNewerThen(date, onChannel: channel, withProgress: { (messages) in
         
        msgs.append(contentsOf: messages)
        if messages.count < 100 { closure(msgs) }
    })
}
     
private func historyNewerThen(_ date: NSNumber, onChannel channel: String, 
                              withProgress closure: @escaping (Array<Any>) -> Void) {
     
    self.client?.historyForChannel(channel, start: date, end: nil, limit: 100, 
                                   reverse: false, withCompletion: { (result, status) in
                                     
        if status == nil {
             
            closure((result?.data.messages)!)
            if result?.data.messages.count == 100 {
                 
                self.historyNewerThen((result?.data.end)!, onChannel: channel, 
                                      withProgress: closure)
            }
        }
        else {
             
            /**
             Handle message history download error. Check 'category' property
             to find out possible reason because of which request did fail.
             Review 'errorData' property (which has PNErrorData data type) of status
             object to get additional information about issue.
              
             Request can be resent using: [status retry];
             */
        }
    })
}
```

Refer to same section in other SDKs language specific implementations.

Comment: Cheers! We're working on better ways to present all the docs that we have. It's a bit complex with so many SDKs but some refactoring is in the near future.